# Is there any way to load part of table from DataBase?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I need to write a function that will generate a report from last week. I use pd.read_sql_table to import table. The problem is that this is taking 10 seconds. This is Postgresql DB. The database has a date column.

This is my code to import the table:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:1234!!!!@11.12.13.14/DB').connect()
df = pd.read_sql_table(table_name='young', con=engine)
```

Is there any solution to import only that part of the table that I need?
Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load just the list of dates, or just a part of columns coming from your table, you have to specify the query using the function [read_query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html?highlight=read_sql#pandas-read-sql) instead of [read_sql_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_table.html?highlight=read_sql_table)

Inside the function read_query(), you can specify the sql for retrieving the data just from the desired column(columns.

here's a code snippet that should work:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:1234!!!!@11.12.13.14/DB').connect()
query = "SELECT <date column> FROM <my table>"
df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=engine)
```

is better to use pandas Series instead of dataframes if you read data from just one column (i think that pandas automatically generates series in this case).

EDIT:

looking back at your question, if i understood correctly, you need to retrieve the data from your table from last week.

one way, keeping my example above, is structuring the query, adding a WHERE condition, and filter out the dates that are older than a week ago

here's an example:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:1234!!!!@11.12.13.14/DB').connect()
query = """SELECT *
           FROM <my table>
           WHERE <date column> <= {date}""".format(date=<calculated_date>)
df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=engine)
```

Comment: Thanks so much i try this and it work rly good. Thanks again case closed :D

Comment: glad to hear :) if this is works as expected for you, please mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

use chunksize as follows:

```
df_iterator = pd.read_sql_table(your_table_name, con=engine, chunksize=num_rows_you_want)
```

it returns an iterator but you can get the first batch by:

```
df = next(df_iterator)
```